# How to remove a button when it is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, subview

I'm very new to **swift**. I've created `multiple textfield and button` by using `subview`. The output of my `ViewController` is below:- [image: here]

Now I need to remove `"-"` button and it's corresponding `textfield` when it is clicked.
But I'm not able to detect which button is being clicked.
This is my code:

```
var y: CGFloat = 190
var by: CGFloat = 192

 @IBAction func addRow(sender: AnyObject) {

    y += 30
    by += 30

    let textFiled = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(50.0, y, 100.0, 20.0))

    textFiled.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line

    let dunamicButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(155.0, by, 15.0, 15.0))
    dunamicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    dunamicButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    dunamicButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    dunamicButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    dunamicButton.backgroundColor = .grayColor()
    dunamicButton.setTitle("-", forState: .Normal)
    dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeRow), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)




    self.view.addSubview(textFiled)
    self.view.addSubview(dunamicButton)
}


func removeRow(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: tried using tags for buttons??

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: You need somehow pair your buttons with textfelds (using dictionary, arrays). Then, when button is tapped, remove it from dictionary and from view using sender.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora No. Please don't use tags, this is a bad practice

Comment: @Antzi ok. won't use tag. But will U kindly help me. How'll I achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eMKA was right! Try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var y:CGFloat = 100
    var textFields = [UIButton : UITextField]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func onAddMoreButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let newButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: y, width: 150, height: 20))


        newButton.setTitle("New button", forState: .Normal)
        newButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.onNewButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(newButton)

        let newTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: y, width: 150, height: 20))
        newTextField.text = "New text field"
        self.view.addSubview(newTextField)

        textFields[newButton] = newTextField

        y += 20
        if y > self.view.frame.height {
            y = 100
        }
    }

    func onNewButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        textFields[sender]?.removeFromSuperview()
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Comment: This concept is working fine. but problem is Y is not updating. so gap is still there. r there any solution for this?

Comment: What is not updating? View, dictionary?

Comment: You have hardcoded coordination of your buttons and textfields. If You want to move other pairs up, You need to do this manually. Lets say, when you remove button, You can loop over dictionary and update coordinates of rest of Your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method `touchesBegan` in any view controller. Assuming that you are storing an array of your buttons somewhere

```
let buttons : [UIButton] = []
```

you can do the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    guard let touch: UITouch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    for button in buttons {
        if touch.view == button {
            print("This is the button you tapped")
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting "uncaught exception" error in this function.

Comment: Well, this answer is based on the assumption that you are storing your views somewhere and is meant to be a guide, not the final answer. You need to give more details on that error so I can help you.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
-- this error